# How can the input parameter of a LINQ to Objects expression be null

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have a collection of objects that I am trying to query with LINQ. Inexplicably, the code is crashing when querying for a specific value.

```
SomeObject[] myObjects = { ... };

foreach (int id in someIDs)
{
    SomeObject singleObject = myObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID = id);
}
```

This code is failing when the value of `id` is a specific value. The error I get is that `x` is NULL. The `myObjects` array is not NULL, and does contain an object with an `ID` value that matches the value of `id` that is failing. Other values of `id` do not cause the error. When `id` is the value that is failing, I can step through the LINQ expression as it iterates through the items in the array. The parameter `x` has a value for every item in the collection up until it reaches the item before the item that matches the problematic value of `id`; at that point `x` suddenly becomes NULL and an exception is thrown.

How could the input parameter of a LINQ expression on a non-NULL collection ever be NULL? Even if the collection did not contain an item with `ID` matching `id`, it should just return the default value for my object type, not crash with a NULL error.

Comment: It isn't saying that `myObjects` is `null`, it's saying that an **element member** of `myObjects` is `null`. E.g. `SomeObject[] myObjects = new[] { foo, bar, null, baz };`.

Comment: `x => x != null && x.ID = id`

Comment: Also, your posted code has poor runtime complexity (`O( n * m )`). You should convert `myObjects` to a dictionary first (outside of the loop) so you get `O(1)` lookup inside the loop and `O( n )` overall performance.

Comment: `myObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x?.ID == id);`

Comment: @Dai, thanks. I was getting confused because the collection shouldn't have contained any nulls. Turns out a bug further up the line had been inserting nulls into the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the nulls *and* improve runtime performance drastically like so:

```
SomeObject[] myObjects = new[] { ... };

Dictionary<Int32,SomeObject> dict = myObjects
    .Where( mo => mo != null )
    .ToDictionary( mo => mo.id );

foreach( Int32 id in someIds )
{
    if( dict.TryGetValue( id, out SomeObject singleObject ) )
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
    else
    {
        // don't do stuff here
    }
}
```